# How to query a separate dataset repeatedly for each row in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following simple data in Google Sheets and I'd like to automatically extend the results of a `query` result.
[image]

In G3 I have:

```
=product(QUERY(A3:C, "Select C where B='Z' and A<date'"&TEXT(F3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "))
```

which returns the product of numbers in column C for the dates that are prior to F1, and where B is 'Z' (2*5=10). For some reason, this does not expand to all of column F when I use an arrayformula in H3:

```
=arrayformula(product(QUERY(A3:C, "Select C where B='Z' and A<date'"&TEXT(F3:F,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")))
```

Seems like it isn't enough to just edit the query to include the `F3:F` range, instead of the single `F3` cell. So are there any solutions or workarounds for this?

Comment: How do you want it to expand? The query formula `where` clauses are  still the same `where B='Z' and A<date'"&TEXT(F3:F,"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: The clause is different, F3:F is meant to extend to all the data in the F column.

Answer (score 1):

Product is rather like MAX and MIN, it processes a range or array globally and AFAIK you can't get it to process the rows one at a time.

Here is a first cut at an alternative approach, for fixed ranges and assuming that there are no zeroes in column C:

```
=ArrayFormula(10^mmult((F3:F12>transpose(A3:A6))*(transpose(B3:B6)="Z"),log10(C3:C6)))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the formula for variable ranges using Indirect:

```
=ArrayFormula(10^mmult((indirect("F3:F"&count(F:F)+2)>transpose(indirect("A3:A"&count(A:A)+2)))*(transpose(indirect("B3:B"&count(A:A)+2))="Z"),log10(indirect("C3:C"&count(A:A)+2))))
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a possible workaround for the case where there can be zeroes in column C. Zeroes don't really mix with logs, but you can get round it by adding a large negative exponent:

```
=ArrayFormula(10^mmult((indirect("F3:F"&count(F:F)+2)>transpose(indirect("A3:A"&count(A:A)+2)))*(transpose(indirect("B3:B"&count(A:A)+2))="Z"),log10(indirect("C3:C"&count(A:A)+2)+1E-99)))
```